# Magento layer navigation possition

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

I want show first layer navigation then product list how i make this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
.catalog-category-view .main.container {display: flex;flex-direction: column;}
    .catalog-category-view .col-main {order: 2 !important;}
    .catalog-category-view .col-left {order: 1 !important;}
```

I also face same problem so i fix in this way only use media query only for mobile or your device where ever you want

Comment: This will work with out change layout files

Answer (score 1):

in your theme catalog.xml file is responsible for this.

1) go to `app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/layout/catalog.xml`

2) find `catalog_category_layered` handler.in that file below code responsible for adding in left side

```
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

3) replace above code with below

```
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```